# RabbitMQ Architecture Gut Check

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue

So I'm thinking of using `RabbitMQ` to send messages between all the varied apps in our organization. In the attached image is essentially the picture in my mind of how things would work.

So the message goes into the exchange, and splits out into three queues.

Payloads are always JSON text.

The consumers are long-running windows services whose only job is to sit and listen for messages destined for their particular application.When a message comes in, they look at the header to determine how this payload JSON should be interpreted, and which REST endpoint it should be sent to. e.g., "When I see a `'WORK_ORDER_COMPLETE'` header I am going to parse this as a `WorkOrderCompleteDto` and send it as a `POST` to the CompletedWorkOrder WebAPI method at `timelabor-api.mycompany.com`. If the API returns other than 200, I reject the message and let rabbit handle it. If I get a 200 back from the API, then I ack the message to rabbit."

Then end applications are simply our internal line-of-business apps that we use for inventory, billing, etc. Those applications are then responsible for performing their respective function (decrementing inventory, creating a billing record, yadda yadda.

Does this in any way make a sensible understanding of a proper way to use Rabbit?

[image]

Comment: Yes. This is in general a typical usage of RabbitMQ. Take care how you configure the exchange, so that messages end up in correct queues. Fanout will spam the message to all queues.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, I believe you may be relying on RabbitMQ to do things that your application needs to do.

The assumption of the architecture seems to be that each message is processed by each of your consuming applications totally in a vacuum. What this means is that you don't care that a message processed successfully by `Billing_App` ultimately failed with `Inventory_App`. Maybe this is true, but in my experience, it isn't.

If the end goal is to achieve some consistent state in the overall data, you're going to need a some supervisory component orchestrating and monitoring the various operations to ensure that the state is consistent. This means, in effect, that your statement about rejecting a message back to RabbitMQ means you have a bit more thought to put into what happens when something fails.

I would focus on identifying some UML activity diagrams that describe your behavior and how it achieves the end-state, and use that as a guide to determine how the orchestration of your application needs to be designed.

Comment: OK, so maybe the maintenance app would create a new unique key (e.g. a GUID) that is part of the payload (or headers). As each of the consumers succeed or fail with their task, they could in turn send a message to a "transaction" message exchange, that would ultimately record (in a database, let;'s say) the success or failure of each component of the transaction. That data could in turn be alerted or reported on

Comment: That might work. I do like the fact that you're processing events -> a huge mistake I often see is that processing responds to commands, which then leave the system in an inconsistent and inscrutable state. At least processing events, you always have a way to recover from a failure.